# How to access object that I'm addressing from a method

Tags: objective-c

I guess this is a very basic question, but anyway I don't know how to call this approach therefore I cannot find it anywhere online.

Let's say I have an object `myImg`:

```
UIImageView *myImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImg.png"]];
```

And a method:

```
-(void)myMethod {
  // access myImg and change something on it
}
```

How can I access `myImg` object within `myMethod` when I fire it:

```
[myImg myMethod];
```

Is it even possible or do I have to create a custom class for UIImageView with my custom method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've declared `myMethod` in a category of `UIImageView` then you can reference `myImg` by using `self`.

```
@interface UIImageView (Category)

- (void)myMethod;

@end

@implementation UIImageView (Category)

- (void)myMethod
{
//    reference self here for reference to myImg
}

@end
```

Comment: That's the thing, I want to declare this method within a UIViewController.

Comment: Well that's why I'm asking if it's even possible to do that.

Comment: @jesteuvidim  No. It's done the way I just explained.

Comment: I think this answer is probably the most correct, since I didn't really know what was the right approach. Anyway, vborra provided a great documentation resource, but his edit to myMethod doesn't really work so I'm gonna mark this one as correct.

Comment: @jesteuvidim Keep in mind that this is also a working implementation of the method. If you create a header and an implementation file and paste these code snippets into them, you'll have a working category on UIImageView.

Comment: I created category on UIImageView, added your code and it works great, thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

change the method to:

```
-(void)myMethod:(UIImageView *myImg) {
   // access myImg and change something on it
 }
```

**UPDATE:** You are looking for how to implement a category. See the following link, provided by apple https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: I want to use this method on multiple objects, I guess this is gonna work only on myImg object, am I right?

Comment: The you need to look into singletons or a Category. Check the following link for info on the later: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html

Comment: By implementing a category, you can call your custom method on ANY UIImageView

Comment: If my answer helped you, then be sure to mark it as correct :) an upvite would be nice ;)

Comment: Your link helped me, thanks a lot, but you're answer isn't correct therefore I cannot mark it as correct, but I'll give you upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Add a property to the class that you're declaring the method in:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *myImg;
```

Then change your line where you create the `UIImageView`:

```
self.myImg = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImg.png"]];
```

Then from your method, you can access the `UIImageView` by referencing `self.myImg`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with what he is asking for, he is asking on how to extend a specific class(UIImageView), see my answer

Comment: @vborra No, he's asking how he can reference his image view in that method, and only mentions a custom class because he doesn't know if that's what he needs to do or not.

Comment: He is asking on how to implement a category :) he dosent quite express it adequetely...